# How to connect to azure kubernetes API?

Tags: azure, api, azure-aks

I've deployed in Azure a cluster kubernetes with Azure Ad Integration and RBAC. I'm trying to use the kubernetes api using a user account but I don't know how to get a authentification token.

In order to get the kubernetes config file, I'm calling the azure api endpoint "ListCLusterUserCredentials" (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/rest/api/aks/managed-clusters/list-cluster-user-credentials). But no token is provided in the encoded file.

It works perfectly with the endpoint "ListCLusterAdminCredentials". The config file contains a token that could be used to be authenticated to the kubernetes api. But I don't want give access to the users to this endpoint. There are not suppose to get admin cred if they are only users with read mode.

Do you know how to handle this type of connection ?

Comment: Did you try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough#connect-to-the-cluster ?

Comment: Yes but there is nothing to do with my question

Comment: On clusters that use Azure AD, users with the clusterUser role have an empty kubeconfig file that prompts a log in. Once logged in, users have access based on their Azure AD user or group settings. Users with the clusterAdmin role have admin access.

Clusters that do not use Azure AD only use the clusterAdmin role.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/control-kubeconfig-access#available-cluster-roles-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ListCLusterAdminCredentials`, I use `listClusterMonitoringUserCredential` to get access token to connect to Kubernetes API endpoints.